# Could using Sequential Guid as primary key in SQL Server lead to low performance for big data?

Tags: sql, .net, database-performance, guid, sqlperformance

The biggest database that I have experience with has been a SQL Server database in which one of the tables contained 200,000 rows. I used `Guid` as primary key in that database and NOT sequential guid. I experienced no performance issues in that system which had about 30 concurrent users in it.

Recently I have designed and developed an enterprise application development framework. To take advantage of the "Unit of Work" pattern I used a sequential guid as the primary key, so that the records would be ordered physically. Since my experience with big databases is limited to what I just mentioned, I have a serious concern if I will be going to use this framework to develop an enterprise application for a large organization with 1000 concurrent users that will be going to keep millions of records of data using a sequential guid as the primary key will lead to performance issues?

If yes to what extent? And then again if yes, could it be resolved by improving database server hardware (processor and RAM) and then again to what extent?

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience and knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GUID` may seem to be a natural choice for your primary key - and if you really must, you could probably argue to use it for the primary key of the table. What I'd strongly recommend **not to do** is use the `GUID` column as the **clustering key**, which SQL Server does by default, unless you specifically tell it not to.

You really need to keep two issues apart:

1. The **primary key** is a logical construct - one of the candidate keys that uniquely and reliably identifies every row in your table. This can be anything, really - an `INT`, a `GUID`, a string - pick what makes most sense for your scenario.
2. The **clustering key** (the column or columns that define the "clustered index" on the table) - this is a *physical* storage-related thing, and here, a small, stable, ever-increasing data type is your best pick - `INT` or `BIGINT` as your default option.

By default, the primary key on a SQL Server table is also used as the clustering key - but that doesn't need to be that way! I've personally seen massive performance gains when breaking up the previous GUID-based primary / clustered key into two separate keys - the primary (logical) key on the `GUID`, and the clustering (ordering) key on a separate `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column.

As [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) - the *Queen of Indexing* - and others have stated a great many times - a `GUID` as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance.

Yes, I know - there's `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server 2005 and up - but even that is not truly and fully sequential and thus also suffers from the same problems as the `GUID` - just a bit less prominently so.

Then there's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an `INT` with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a `GUID` as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Quick calculation - using `INT` vs. `GUID` as primary and clustering key:

- Base Table with 1'000'000 rows (3.8 MB vs. 15.26 MB)
- 6 nonclustered indexes (22.89 MB vs. 91.55 MB)

**TOTAL: 25 MB vs. 106 MB** - and that's just on a single table!

And yes - a larger size of a table or of an index automatically means more data pages that need to be loaded from disk, held in memory, transferred to the client - all negatively impacting your performance. **How much** impact that has really depends on lots of factors of your database design and your data distribution, so any generalized predictions are next to impossible...

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Comment: You propose to use SequentialGuid as non-clustered primary key and a bigint column as Clustered-index and thanks for that great solution. But if set the SquentialGuid primary key column as clustered-index and don't use the bigint column, then in this specific manner your opinion is that it will lead to performance issues?!

Comment: @Karamafrooz: well, sequential GUID is certainly better than a random one - but if you have lots of rows and several nonclustered indices, the **clustering key** is added to each and every entry of every single NC index - and sequential GUID is still twice the size of a bigint, so that does add a lot more overhead, which is detrimental to performance

Comment: Thanks again and thanks again and thanks again! Very clear and helpful answer :) I will absolutely go with your solution

Answer (score 1):

The issue of sequential GUID versus "regular" GUIDs comes up in the following circumstance:

- The GUID column is part of a primary or clustered index (particularly the only key in the index).
- Your database has "lots" of inserts on it.

For a clustered index, SQL Server adds new records to the table "in order".  So, larger values go at the "end" of the table -- in this case, on the last data page.  This is handy for identity columns because they are guaranteed to be larger than any previous value.  And the last data page is -- by definition -- not fragmented.

GUIDs do not have this property.  They end up being inserted "in the middle", causing fragmentation.

Why do you not see this as a problem?  There could be various reasons:

- Your application is not doing many inserts.
- You are defragging the table on a regular basis.
- The table is so small that this is almost irrelevant.

As for the latter point, if the records are small enough, then over a thousand could appear on each page.  With 200 pages of data, fragmentation might not be a significant issue.

With 30 concurrent users, you might simply have no overlap of transactions.  If each user modified the database once per minute, that gives you 2 seconds to complete a transaction -- typically quite enough time.

Nevertheless, I recommend using a sequential GUID or identity column.  This will keep the database cleaner.  However, regularly defragging the database is another option that might work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that you did not read my question very carefully, I already know the issues with using Guid, and that's why I have used Sequential Guid in my framework, The concern that I declared in my question was exactly about using sequential guid and how will that be from performance perspective for big data

Comment: @Karamafrooz . . . Your question is not at all clear then.  What performance issues are you concerned about?  Sequential GUIDs eliminate the issue of data page fragmentation on loads.  Do you have some suspicion that they cause some other problem?  Why not just use `identity` columns, which are smaller and so should have better performance characteristics?